# hadoop reduce has problems in the progress prompt

Tags: hadoop, reduce

I found out job.getReduceProgress() not updated, but in Reducer context, context.getProgress() has a specific task schedule, why does the progress in job not updated in time?

Comment: What do you mean "reduce progress is not updated in real time, but is counted with the end of the reduce node task"? Like, is the reduce progress going straight to 100%? Can you provide output examples for both cases of 2 Hadoop versions, as well as the source code of the job you are running?

Comment: when I set reduce num to 1, the reduce progress going straight to 100%, when I set reduce num to 3, the progress from "map 100% reduce 0%" to "map 100% reduce 33%" cost 6min, from "map 100% reduce 33%" to "map 100% reduce 100%" cost 20s. When I set reduce num to 6, the following progress value will appear:17%,33%,50%,67%,83%,100%.
But in hadoop 2.7.3, Before the map starts, reduce has already started，from reduce 1% to reduce 100%, about 5s update once.

Comment: @Coursal sorry, i don't know how to upload images:
2020-12-08 17:30:01.027  INFO 43248 --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          :  map 100% reduce 0%
2020-12-08 17:38:49.070  INFO 43248 --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          :  map 100% reduce 17%
2020-12-08 17:39:29.838  INFO 43248 --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job          :  map 100% reduce 33%

Comment: That really depends on the job you are running, where it actually might be way more efficient to *not* split data to many reducers. You need to edit the question with more info as well as the source code of the application you are running in order to help you.

Comment: @Coursal I try the same code (same job) in both hadoop-2.7.3 and hadoop-3.3.0, but it works well in 2.7.3. now i am trying another hadoop version